# R Flexsurv and time-dependent covariates

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I read that the R flexsurv package can also be used for modeling time-dependent covariates according to Christopher Jackson (2016) ["flexsurv: a platform for parametric survival modeling in R, Journal of Statistical Software, 70 (1)].

However, I was not able to figure out how, even after several adjustments and searches in online forums.

Before turning to the estimation of time-dependent covariates I tried to create a simple model with only time-independent covariates to test whether I specified the Surv object correctly. Here is a small example.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(flexsurv)

## create sample data
n=50
set.seed(2)
t <- rpois(n,15)+1
x <- rnorm(n,t,5)
df <- data.frame(t,x)
df$id <- 1:n
df$rep <- df$t-1
```

Which looks like this:

```
  t         x id rep
1 12 17.696149  1  11
2 12 20.358094  2  11
3 11  2.058789  3  10
4 16 26.156213  4  15
5 13  9.484278  5  12
6 15 15.790824  6  14
...
```

And the long data:

```
long.df <- expandRows(df, "rep")

rep.vec<-c()
for(i in 1:n){
  rep.vec <- c(rep.vec,1:(df[i,"t"]-1))
}

long.df$start <- rep.vec 
long.df$stop  <- rep.vec +1
long.df$censrec <- 0
long.df$censrec<-ifelse(long.df$stop==long.df$t,1,long.df$censrec)
```

Which looks like this:

```
     t         x id start stop censrec
1    12 17.69615  1     1    2       0
1.1  12 17.69615  1     2    3       0
1.2  12 17.69615  1     3    4       0
1.3  12 17.69615  1     4    5       0
1.4  12 17.69615  1     5    6       0
1.5  12 17.69615  1     6    7       0
1.6  12 17.69615  1     7    8       0
1.7  12 17.69615  1     8    9       0
1.8  12 17.69615  1     9   10       0
1.9  12 17.69615  1    10   11       0
1.10 12 17.69615  1    11   12       1
2    12 20.35809  2     1    2       0

...
```

Now I can estimate a simple Cox model to see whether it works:

```
coxph(Surv(t)~x,data=df)
```

This yields:

```
    coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
x -0.0588    0.9429   0.0260 -2.26 0.024
```

And in the long format:

```
coxph(Surv(start,stop,censrec)~x,data=long.df)
```

I get:

```
     coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
x -0.0588    0.9429   0.0260 -2.26 0.024
```

Taken together I conclude that my transformation into the long format was correct. Now, turning to the flexsurv framework:

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(time=t)~x,data=df, dist="weibull")
```

yields:

```
Estimates: 
       data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)  L95%      U95%    
shape        NA    5.00086   4.05569   6.16631   0.53452        NA        NA        NA
scale        NA   13.17215  11.27876  15.38338   1.04293        NA        NA        NA
x      15.13380    0.01522   0.00567   0.02477   0.00487   1.01534   1.00569   1.02508
```

**But**

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(start,stop,censrec) ~ x ,data=long.df, dist="weibull")
```

causes an error:

```
Error in flexsurvreg(Surv(start, stop, censrec) ~ x, data = long.df, dist = "weibull") : 
  Initial value for parameter 1 out of range
```

Would anyone happen to know the correct syntax for the latter Surv object? If you use the correct syntax, do you get the same estimates?

Thank you very much,
best,
David

===============

**EDIT AFTER FEEDBACK FROM 42**

===============

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(flexsurv)
x<-c(8.136527,  7.626712,  9.809122, 12.125973, 12.031536, 11.238394,  4.208863,  8.809854,  9.723636)
t<-c(2, 3, 13,  5,  7, 37 ,37,  9,  4)

df <- data.frame(t,x)

#transform into long format for time-dependent covariates
df$id <- 1:length(df$t)
df$rep <- df$t-1
long.df <- expandRows(df, "rep")

rep.vec<-c()
for(i in 1:length(df$t)){
    rep.vec <- c(rep.vec,1:(df[i,"t"]-1))
}

long.df$start <- rep.vec 
long.df$stop  <- rep.vec +1
long.df$censrec <- 0
long.df$censrec<-ifelse(long.df$stop==long.df$t,1,long.df$censrec)


coxph(Surv(t)~x,data=df)
coxph(Surv(start,stop,censrec)~x,data=long.df)

flexsurvreg(Surv(time=t)~x,data=df, dist="weibull")
flexsurvreg(Surv(start,stop,censrec) ~ x ,data=long.df, dist="weibull",inits=c(shape=.1, scale=1))
```

Which yields the same estimates for both coxph models but

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time = t) ~ x, data = df, dist = "weibull")

Estimates: 
       data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)  L95%      U95%    
shape        NA     1.0783    0.6608    1.7594    0.2694        NA        NA        NA
scale        NA    27.7731    3.5548  216.9901   29.1309        NA        NA        NA
x        9.3012    -0.0813   -0.2922    0.1295    0.1076    0.9219    0.7466    1.1383

N = 9,  Events: 9,  Censored: 0
Total time at risk: 117
Log-likelihood = -31.77307, df = 3
AIC = 69.54614
```

and

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(start, stop, censrec) ~ x, data = long.df, 
    dist = "weibull", inits = c(shape = 0.1, scale = 1))

Estimates: 
       data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)  L95%      U95%    
shape        NA     0.8660    0.4054    1.8498    0.3353        NA        NA        NA
scale        NA    24.0596    1.7628  328.3853   32.0840        NA        NA        NA
x        8.4958    -0.0912   -0.3563    0.1739    0.1353    0.9128    0.7003    1.1899

N = 108,  Events: 9,  Censored: 99
Total time at risk: 108
Log-likelihood = -30.97986, df = 3
AIC = 67.95973
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your intent. Some comments about what is a final event, what is a censoring event and what are the covariates that vary from time period to time period would be helpful.

Comment: My apologies. With `t` I refer to the time until final event (e.g. machine breakdown). With `censrec` I denote whether at the end of an interval a breakdown has been observed. In this simple case it is 0 for all intervals with stop time before `t`. I excluded (for now) covariates that vary over time to test whether the model specification is correct (hence the time intervals are somewhat arbitrary). Without time varying covariates I'd expect both flexsurvreg models to have the same estimates. So my intent it to setup the model correctly before adding time varying covariates in a next step.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message:

> Error in flexsurvreg(Surv(start, stop, censrec) ~ x, data = long.df, dist = "weibull",  : 
>     initial values must be a numeric vector

And then reading the help page, `?flexsurvreg`, it seemed as though an attempt at setting values for `inits` to a named numeric vector should be attempted:

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(start,stop,censrec) ~ x ,data=long.df, dist="weibull", inits=c(shape=.1, scale=1))
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(start, stop, censrec) ~ x, data = long.df, 
    dist = "weibull", inits = c(shape = 0.1, scale = 1))

Estimates: 
       data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)  L95%      U95%    
shape        NA    5.00082   4.05560   6.16633   0.53454        NA        NA        NA
scale        NA   13.17213  11.27871  15.38341   1.04294        NA        NA        NA
x      15.66145    0.01522   0.00567   0.02477   0.00487   1.01534   1.00569   1.02508

N = 715,  Events: 50,  Censored: 665
Total time at risk: 715
Log-likelihood = -131.5721, df = 3
AIC = 269.1443
```

Extremely similar results. My guess was basically a stab in the dark, so I have no guidance on how to make a choice if this had not succeeded other than to "expand the search."

Comment: Thank you very much! This does help indeed. When running this example with your edit I get the same results. However, when I use data based on a real distribution, the estimates differ:

`x<-c(8.136527,  7.626712,  9.809122, 12.125973, 12.031536, 11.238394,  4.208863,  8.809854,  9.723636)`
`t<-c(2, 3, 13,  5,  7, 37 ,37,  9,  4)`

I edited my former question by adding the complete code. Do you get the same differing estimates?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that in *flexsurv* v1.1.1, running this code:

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(start,stop,censrec) ~ x ,data=long.df, dist="weibull")
```

doesn't return any errors. It also gives the same estimates as the non time-varying command

```
flexsurvreg(Surv(time=t)~x,data=df, dist="weibull")
```

[image]